# only retrieving 1 row of data from MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to input multiple pieces of data through a form and all the data will be separated by (,). I plan to use this data to find the corresponding id for further processing through an sql query.

Below is the code I use.

```
$key_code = explode(",", $keyword); 
 //$key_count = count($key_code);
 $list = "'". implode("','", $key_code) ."'";
 //$row_count = '';
 $sql4= "SELECT key_id FROM keyword WHERE key_code IN (".$list.")";
 if(!$result4 = mysql_query($sql4, $connect)) {
 mysql_close($connect);
 $error = true;
 }else{
  //$i = 0;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4)) {
  $keyword_id[] = $row['key_id'];
   //$i++;
   } 
   //return $keyword_id;   
  }
```

The problem i see is that keyword_id[0] is the only element that contains any data (the data is accurate). Even if I input multiple values through the aforementioned form.

I thought it might be an error in the sql but I echo'ed it and it looks like:

```
SELECT key_id FROM keyword WHERE key_code IN ('WED','WATER','WASTE')
```

The values in the brackets are exactly what I inputted.

I even tried to figure out how many rows are being returned by the query and it shows only 1. I assume something is wrong with my query but I cannot figure where.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

***Edit***: Alright **Solved the problem.** Thanks to suggestions made I copied and pasted the $sql_query I had echo'ed on the website into mysql console; which resulted in only 1 row being retrieved. After taking a closer look I realized that there was a whitespace between ' and the second word. I believe the problem starts when I input the key_code as:

> WED, WATER, WASTE

Instead inputting it as

> WED,WATER,WASTE

fixes the problem. I think I should make it so that it works both ways though.

Anyway, thank you for the help.

Comment: How much data is in the table?  The echo'd SQL statement looks fine, so the next thing to check is that the `KEYWORD.key_code` column actually has any of those three values.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the query is ok. How many rows do you get with just

```
SELECT key_id FROM keyword
```

I think that there is just one line that matches your WHERE.

Comment: Off the top of my head keyword table has more than 200rows.

Answer (score 0):

Check the query directly in the database(with phpmyadmin, or in the mysql console), however this query seems to be working as you may assumed. If it returns only 1 row when you use it directly in the db, then maybe there is only one row in your table wich matches this query.

Comment: I have tried the query directly in MySQL console and I have found all 3 ids.